# mode rewrite general rule to hide dynamic url elements?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's what I have:

`www.name.com/category.php?title=111-hello-kitty`

This is what I would like:

`www.name.com/category/111-hello-kitty`

Also is it possible to hide the number part in htaccess so it looks like this:

`www.name.com/category/hello-kitty`

Here's my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /?title=$1
```

Obviously, the last line is not working.

Can I call in general to have all `?anything=` to be replaced by a / like the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My thoughts:**

- **Hiding the number will require some SQL changes.** This is because you no longer have the  ID available to you, now you have to query the database to get it.
- **I would use `www.name.com/category/111/hello-kitty/` for my URL.** The reason is that this way you can systematically parse each portion.  Notice that this is also what StackOverflow is using.  The following RewriteRule assumes that `category` and the section for `hello-kitty` contains only alphanumeric symbols and a dash (a common practice):

---

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /$1.php?title=$2-$3

#although I'd recommend that you really do this:
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/[A-Za-z0-9-]+/?$ /$1.php?id=$2
```

Comment: I keep getting 500 Internal Server Error. would this work in any directory for any file passing variable id/title? ex: `http://name.com/dir/file.php?title=111-hello-kitty`

Comment: If you supply `/dir/100/hi-there`, my rule would rewrite that to `/dir.php?title=100-hi-there` in the former or `/dir.php?id=100` in the latter.  Does that make sense?  In order to use a directory before it, you would need to prefix the rule with the directory.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll keep trying. So putting this at the end of my own rewrite rules should give me the effect I want? `RewriteRule ^/dir/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /dir/$1.php?title=$2-$3`

Comment: ok I got it to work. thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

RewriteRule ^category(/.+)?$ /category.php [L]